# The Formula is not working because of dropdowns?

Tags: excel, google-docs

Hi so i am making a planning for a team of 5 and each member have a table to put his availability by chosing from a dropdown if he is available ( dispo ) or not ( Pas Dispo ) or not sure ( Maybe ) and now i want to make a final table for the whole team that change depending on the availability of each if one is not available it show (Rien) and if all available then show (Libre) and if one is Maybe it show and no one ( Pas Dispo ) then it show Maybe , i tried asking chat gpt but the formula it gives me didnt work

```
=IF(
  COUNTIF(A16:H28, "Pas Dispo") + 
  COUNTIF(A32:H44, "Pas Dispo") + 
  COUNTIF(A48:H60, "Pas Dispo") + 
  COUNTIF(A64:H76, "Pas Dispo") + 
  COUNTIF(A80:H92, "Pas Dispo") > 0,
  "Pas Dispo",
  IF(
    COUNTIF(A16:H28, "Maybe") + 
    COUNTIF(A32:H44, "Maybe") + 
    COUNTIF(A48:H60, "Maybe") + 
    COUNTIF(A64:H76, "Maybe") + 
    COUNTIF(A80:H92, "Maybe") > 0,
    "Maybe",
    "Dispo"
  )
)
```

```
=IF(
  OR(
    COUNTIF(B18:H28, "Pas Dispo") > 0,
    COUNTIF(B34:H44, "Pas Dispo") > 0,
    COUNTIF(B50:H60, "Pas Dispo") > 0,
    COUNTIF(B66:H76, "Pas Dispo") > 0,
    COUNTIF(B82:H92, "Pas Dispo") > 0
  ),
  "Pas Dispo",
  IF(
    OR(
      COUNTIF(B18:H28, "Maybe") > 0,
      COUNTIF(B34:H44, "Maybe") > 0,
      COUNTIF(B50:H60, "Maybe") > 0,
      COUNTIF(B66:H76, "Maybe") > 0,
      COUNTIF(B82:H92, "Maybe") > 0
    ),
    "Maybe",
    "Dispo"
  )
)
```

i tried both this and i dont know how to solve it , if anyone can help me

[the gdoc if anyone want to see it](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13Kn5NDCCW_sIciKY8ob2FSF09-hG_KgMbi0NwAfp4fQ/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: I think you should replace , separator in formula to ;

Answer (score 0):

Apply formula on cell `B98`, filling the formula through all cells in team section.

```
=IF(OR(B18="Pas Dispo",B34="Pas Dispo",B50="Pas Dispo",B66="Pas Dispo",B82="Pas Dispo"),"Rien",
IF(AND(B18="Dispo",B34="Dispo",B50="Dispo",B66="Dispo",B82="Dispo"),"Libre",
IF(AND(OR(B18="Maybe",B34="Maybe",B50="Maybe",B66="Maybe",B82="Maybe"),NOT(OR(B18="Pas Dispo",B34="Pas Dispo",B50="Pas Dispo",B66="Pas Dispo",B82="Pas Dispo"))),"Maybe",
"N.A.")))
```

---

`LET` formula is simpler, but it only works with Excel 365.

```
=LET(
pd,OR(B18="Pas Dispo",B34="Pas Dispo",B50="Pas Dispo",B66="Pas Dispo",B82="Pas Dispo"),
di,AND(B18="Dispo",B34="Dispo",B50="Dispo",B66="Dispo",B82="Dispo"),
ma,OR(B18="Maybe",B34="Maybe",B50="Maybe",B66="Maybe",B82="Maybe"),
IF(pd,"Rien",IF(di,"Libre",IF(AND(ma,NOT(pd)),"Maybe","N.A.")))
)
```

---

Credit to `user11222393`, make the formula shorter with `HSTACK` (Excel 365 only).

```
=LET(
rng,HSTACK(B18,B34,B50,B66,B82),
pd,SUM(--(rng="Pas Dispo"))>0,
di,SUM(--(rng="Dispo"))=5,
ma,SUM(--(rng="Maybe"))>0,
IF(pd,"Rien",IF(di,"Libre",IF(AND(ma,NOT(pd)),"Maybe","N.A.")))
)
```

[image]

Comment: You could shorten a bit by using  h or v stacking. For example OR(B18="Pas Dispo",B34="Pas Dispo",B50="Pas Dispo",B66="Pas Dispo",B82="Pas Dispo") to SUM(N(HSTACK(B18,B34,B50,B66,B82)="Pas Dispo"))>0